# Retrieve data from nested array

Tags: arrays, angular, nested

I've tried pretty much everything but I keep on struggeling with the HTML of retrieving my array.

I do get a list of teams but the players (childs) of each team do not appear.

It should be like;

- TEAM A
- - PLAYER1
- - PLAYER2

**HTML**

```
 <h3>Registered teams</h3>
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor='let team of teams;let i = index'>{{ team.Name }} (id: {{ team.id }})
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let players of team.players;let j = index'>{{ player.Name }} ({{ players.id }})</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JSON**

```
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "TEAM A",
    "Active": true,
    "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:52.045Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.533Z",
    "Players": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "PLAYER1",
        "Active": null,
        "created_at": "2019-09-12T13:56:41.496Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "Name": "PLAYER2",
        "Active": true,
        "created_at": "2019-09-12T14:00:12.149Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-12T14:30:42.540Z"
      }
```

**model.ts**

```
export class Team {
id: number;
name: string;
active: boolean;
players: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is returning`Players` and you are referencing `players` and you wrote `let players of team.players`.

It should be:

`<li *ngFor='let players of team.Players;let j = index'>{{ players.Name }} ({{ players.id }})</li>`